# Getting Calculated Filed Data into Links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I know I can make links with calculated fields; however, I am having a hard time getting the value of a column I need within the URL.  Here is my code.  I think I am close here but still having problems:

```
="<div><a href='http://hsvspsd01vm/Lists/Play%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID="&TEXT([Link ID], ' ')"'">Link to Information</a></div>"
```

Any ideas would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just incase any of you want to do something similar:

```
=CONCATENATE("<div><a href='http://hsvspsd01vm/Lists/Play%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=",[Link ID], "'>Link to Information</a></div>")
```

Link ID has to be filled out but at least you can create a semi-dynamic link here :)